# How to install ant in an iron.io worker

Tags: iron.io, ironworker

I am using an iron.io node.js worker. I have ant as a dependency. How can I install this?
I could only see the instructions for language specific dependencies installations (like node modules).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably include the linux x64 binary distribution along with your worker by including the 
"dir" command in your .worker file. Something like:

dir "apache-ant-1.9.4"

That will include the entire directory in your worker package.

Hit us up at [get.iron.io/chat](http://get.iron.io/chat) for help.